# How to send text to elements using selenium without names or IDs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

So, I am trying to automate the process of downloading reports for one of my functions.  The problem I am running into is that this specific site does not have a name or ID for the Username and password fields.  Has anyone dealt with an issue like this before?

Here is the username field:

```
<input type="text" value="user" placeholder="username@whitehatsec.com" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" style="background-image:
 url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;);
background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
```

Here is the password field:

```
<input type="password" value="pass" placeholder="Enter your password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" style="background-image:
 url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;);
 background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
```

Comment: There are half-dozen different ways of locating elements! https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However, the problem I have is that these particular fields have the exact same XPATH and do not have any of the other attributes.  As far as I can tell the only thing that sets these two field apart are the placeholder and input type attributes but I don't believe you can search by those.

Comment: One field is `xpath=//input[1]` and the other is `xpath=//input[2]`. There are probably others, but you did not provide sufficient information.

Comment: What do you mean they don't have other attributes? From just what you've posted, you can see that they have differing `value` and `placeholder` attribute values. Did you try those? You need to post what you've actually tried and the results. So we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a character sequence to the *Username* field:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control[value='user'][placeholder='username@whitehatsec.com']").send_keys("DarthDobber")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @value='user'][@placeholder='username@whitehatsec.com']").send_keys("DarthDobber")
  ```

To send a character sequence to the *Password* field:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control[value='pass'][placeholder='Enter your password']").send_keys("DarthDobber")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @value='pass'][@placeholder='Enter your password']").send_keys("DarthDobber")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario: you can use `type` and `placeholder` attributes to locate the element.

Xpath

```
//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='username@whitehatsec.com']
//input[@type='password'][@placeholder='Enter your password']

This also should work
//input[@placeholder='username@whitehatsec.com']
//input[@placeholder='Enter your password']
```

CSS Selector

```
input[type='text'][placeholder='username@whitehatsec.com']
input[type='password'][placeholder='Enter your password']

This also should work
input[placeholder='username@whitehatsec.com']
input[placeholder='Enter your password']
```

It is quite possible that you might have missed some parent element which has some unique identifiers like `form` tag with a name or id. Be on the lookout for them in the html. They can provide better xpaths.